# Width of ImageView not filling parent after load with Picasso (on some device)

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

i'have problem with my imageView, Width of ImageView not filling parent after load with Picasso .

**on nexus 4 and Oppo device:**

[image]

**on nexus 5 and some samsung device:**

[image]

this is XML

```
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_photo_pengaduan"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

and Picasso :

```
            Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(url_phpto)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(holder.img_photo_pengaduan);
```

i want result like on nexus 5. How to this ? thanks

Comment: Thank you sir for the clarification.

Comment: Prefer `match_parent` over `fill_parent` for style points.

Comment: Have you tried [fit()](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fit--)?

Answer (score 0):

adjustViewBounds not work on low version of sdk, you can try set `scaletype` or `layout_width` layout height or `load(x).fitXY().into(x)`